# Does liver reheat well?

Tags: beef, reheating, liver

I have a large chunk of beef liver, too much to eat in one sitting. I would prefer to cook it all up at once, but would it be palatable reheated? Would it be ok cold?

Comment: Liver is extremely heat-sensitive. While it should be possible to reheat it and keep it palatable, it is tricky, because you risk ruining it every time you put it on the heat.

Comment: I know lots of people don't, but I love chopped liver - it's perfectly fine to eat cold (assuming it's been cooked).

Comment: insignificant idiom should be "*cold* chopped liver"? (had to say it)

Comment: If I didn't hate liver with every fiber of my being, I'd consider [pâté](http://www.almostbananas.net/simple-and-best-liver-pate/), which is generally served chilled.

Comment: Beef liver is just so incredibly bad, why would anyone eat it. It is the organ that filters impurities out of the animals blood stream. Even if you are 100 percent certain of the quality of the livestock it still has a terrible mineral quality to it. Nope grind it and feed it to the cats

Answer (score 4):

So this turned out to be delicious. First, slice the cold, cooked liver into strips approximately 1/4 inch thick, then cut strips into bite sized bits, and set aside.  The liver needs to reach room temperature. I then cooked a serving of rice in beef broth instead of water, with the lid off.  In a pan I sautéed onions, bell pepper and carrot in olive oil, all cut fairly small. Once the onion was translucent I added about a 1/4 cup of merlot and let it cook from a few minutes.  I then combined the rice and the onion mixture, covered, and simmered until the rice was cooked.  The I carefully added the liver on top of the rice(do not stir it in) and steamed the liver for a minute and a half.  I removed the mixture from the heat and stirred the. I let it rest for a few minutes.  The liver was still tender and moist.  I will definitely try this again.

Comment: So the crucial information is *“Steam room temperature cooked liver atop rice and veggies for 1.5 minutes, then mix and let rest off the heat for a bit longer”*. Nice suggestion! That said, welcome to Seasoned Advice! If you have a moment, I recommend you take the [tour] and browse through the [help] to learn more about how the site works.

Answer (score 2):

With liver I'd say there isn't much point in reheating it as it'll cook in about the same time if you cut it thinly.
You could eat it cold but whether you'd like it is a matter of personal taste.

Answer (score 2):

I hate to waste food and I always have too much liver.   I use beef broth or bouillon so the liver does not dry out or get tough.

To reheat:

1. Slice up fresh onions if you don't have enough left over onion.
2. Slice cooked liver on the diagonal into 1/2" thick strips.
3. In saucepan, make up enough beef broth or bouillon to completely cover liver in pan (about 3 cups), Keep hot.
4. Saute fresh batch of onions, remove from pan and set aside.
5. Add hot beef broth to pan, lightly scrape bottom to deglaze onion flavor.
6. Add liver to boiling broth for about 30-45 SECONDS, just enough to heat them through. Quickly remove from heat and drain.
7. If desired, quickly toss onions in pan to reheat.

Serve onions over liver strips.

Answer (score 1):

After reading different sources on how to reheat liver, I tried by placing liver and onion in foil wrap, placed in 350 F oven for about 3 to 5 minutes. It came out very decent, not hot, not cold, but edible.

Comment: Hello Bill, we are glad you took the time to tell us about a working method. We would ask you to not use ALL CAPS when posting. On the Interent, this is understood to be the written equivalent of shouting, and comes across as rude. I rewrote your post in normal capitalization now.

Answer (score 1):

I always soak my liver pieces in milk first, this seems to make it less dry.  When ready to cook, drain, pat dry and dredge in a mixture on flour, salt & pepper maybe a herb such as thyme.  Cook in bacon grease, or fry a few slices bacon first, cook 10 min as needed till tender.  Serve as you wish.  My husband will often reheat left-overs in Microwave 1 min., still awesome, not tough.  I would love to try freezing this for later.

Answer (score 0):

Palatability is largely a matter of taste...

Seriously, it will likely depend upon your cooking method.  If you are cooking short high-heat, then reheating may well not work as well, as it will cook further and would likely become tough.

If you originally cooked in some kind of braising sauce, you are probably just fine to gently reheat, as the liquid should help to keep it tender.

Cold - mostly a matter of preference.  OK for me might not be OK for you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I looked at the answers and thought about how to try it.  My 96 year old father said it was too tough when I reheated it the first time.  Like everyone else I had too much left over.  I sauteed more onions until they were almost burnt.  I then cut the heat off and place a piece of liver that I had in the fridge, covered it with the onions and put a lid on it and let it sit for about 10 minutes on the off electric burner.

It was not super hot but he enjoyed it almost as if it was freshly cooked.  Not tough at all.  I can not eat it because of gout.
Oh, I am just learning to cook at 66 years old.